# Mongoose Error: Schema hasn't been registered

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I got an error that Schema hasn't been registered for model "student".

[image]

Here is my code of schema and services respectively.

```js
import { IsString, IsInt } from 'class-validator'

export class studentdto{
  @IsString()
  name:string

  @IsInt()
  rollno:number

  @IsString()
  section:string
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { studentdto } from './student.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CrudService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('student') private readonly studentdto
  ) {}

 async insert(name, rollno, section) {
   const add_stu=await this.studentdto({name,rollno,section})
   return await add_stu.save()
   return "data saved"
 }
}
```

Here is the code of module file of my app

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CrudController } from './crud.controller';
import { CrudService } from './crud.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { studentdto } from './student.dto';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CrudModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'student', schema:"studentdto", collection: 'data' },
    ]), 
  ],
  controllers: [CrudController],
  providers: [CrudService],
})
export class CrudModule {}
```

Comment: can you show me code on student module ?

Comment: i have created crud.module file in my app,I updated my question please check